# Is it possible to upgrade vBulletin forum from 3.5 to 4.0 version?

Tags: upgrade, forum, vbulletin

My site is currenlty running vBulletin **3.5.3** and we want to buy a new version of vBulletin forum which is **4.0** to make an upgrade at - https://www.vbulletin.com.
But as it is written here - https://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/upgrade -

> You can upgrade to the latest version of vBulletin 4: form any version of vBulletin 3 from version 3.6.0 and newer. If your
>   vBulletin version is older than 3.8.0, it is recommended that you
>   upgrade to at least vBulletin 3.8.0 before you can upgrade to
>   vBulletin 4.

but there's no 3.8 version available, so does all this mean that i can not uprade my current forum ? Or i should first buy some intermediate version?

Comment: guys from vbulletin.org gave me an answer - http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=278934

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org gave me an answer - vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=278934